# clearcase create diff between parent and child branches

Tags: diff, clearcase

So the typical way I would create a diff log/patch between two branches in clearcase would to simply create two views and do a typical unix diff. But I have to assume that there is a more clearcase way (and also a '1-liner').

so knowing how to get a list of all files that have been modified on a branch:

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(<BRANCH_NAME>)" -print
```

and knowing how to get the diff formatted output for two separate files:

```
cleartool diff FILE FILE@@/main/PARENT_BRANCH_PATH/LATEST
```

so does anyone see any issues with the following to get a diff for all files that have been changed in a branch?

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(CHILD_BRANCH)" -exec 'cleartool diff -ser $CLEARCASE_PN `echo $CLEARCASE_XPN | sed "s/CHILD_BRANCH/LATEST/"` ' > diff.log
```

Any modifications and comments are greatly welcomed

thanks in advance!

update: any ideas on how to get this too be a unix unified diff would also be greatly appreciated.

update2: So I think I have my solution, thanks go to VonC for sending me in the right directions:

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(CHILD_BRANCH)" -exec 'cleartool get -to $CLEARCASE_PN.prev `echo $CLEARCASE_XPN | sed "s/CHILD_BRANCH/LATEST/"`; diff -u $CLEARCASE_PN.prev $CLEARCASE_PN; rm -f $CLEARCASE_PN.prev' > CHILD_BRANCH.diff
```

the output seems to work, I can read the file in via kompare without complaints.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address the last part of your question.

Comment: Looks great. I have included your solution in my answer below for more visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is sound.

I would simply make sure the `$CLEARCASE_PN` and `$CLEARCASE_XPN` are used with double quotes around them, to take into account with potential spaces in the file path or file name (as illustrated in "[How do I list ClearCase versions without the Fully-qualified version?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806136/6309)").

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(CHILD_BRANCH)" -exec 'cleartool diff -ser "$CLEARCASE_PN" `echo "$CLEARCASE_XPN" | sed "s/CHILD_BRANCH/LATEST/"` ' > diff.log
```

Using simple quotes for the -exec directive is a good idea, as explained in "[`CLEARCASE_XPN` not parsed as variable in clearcase command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11429466/6309)".

---

However, [`cleartool diff`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc%255Fref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm), even with the `-ser` (`-serial`) option don't produce *exactly* an [Unix unified diff format](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html) (or [Unified Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) for short).

The `-diff`(`_format`) option is the closest, as I mention in "[How would you measure inserted / changed / removed code lines (LoC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108212/6309)"

> The `-diff_format` option causes both the headers and differences to be reported in the style of the UNIX and Linux diff utility, writing a list of the changes necessary to convert the first file being compared into the second file.

One idea would be to *not* use `cleartool diff`, but use directly `diff`, since it can access in a dynamic view the right version through the **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)** of the elements found.

---

The [OP ckcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/658115/ckcin)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20664998/6309) is close that what [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664998/clearcase-create-diff-between-parent-and-child-branches#comment30979225_20665241) with cleartool get:

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(CHILD_BRANCH)" -exec 'cleartool get -to $CLEARCASE_PN.prev `echo $CLEARCASE_XPN | sed "s/CHILD_BRANCH/LATEST/"`; diff -u $CLEARCASE_PN.prev $CLEARCASE_PN; rm -f $CLEARCASE_PN.prev' > CHILD_BRANCH.diff
```

> the output seems to work, I can read the file in via kompare without complaints.

In multiple line, for readability:

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(CHILD_BRANCH)" 
  -exec 'cleartool get -to $CLEARCASE_PN.prev 
           `echo $CLEARCASE_XPN | sed "s/CHILD_BRANCH/LATEST/"`; 
         diff -u $CLEARCASE_PN.prev $CLEARCASE_PN; 
         rm -f $CLEARCASE_PN.prev' > CHILD_BRANCH.diff
```

(Note that `$CLEARCASE_XPN` and `$CLEARCASE_PN` are set by the cleartool find commant, they're not variables you set yourself.)

Comment: is there a way to use diff directly with snapshot views?

Comment: @ckcin not easily, considering extended pathname aren't directly readable from a snapshot view (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/177350/6309, although you can actually try a `cleartool get`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18716494/6309). I would stick with dynamic view.

Comment: What `$CLEARCASE_PN` and `$CLEARCASE_XPN` here? who sets then?

Comment: @einpoklum path names and extended path names, set by the `cleartool find` command for each and every elements found by said command (`cleartool find`), fir the `-exec` directive to use.

Answer (score 2):

Transferring the answer from VonC and einpoklum to Windows I came up with the following. Create a separate batch file, which I called `diffClearCase.bat`, this eases up the command line significantly. It creates a separate tree for all modified files, which I personally liked, but the file and folders can be deleted afterwards.

```
@echo off
SET PLAINFILE=%1
SET PLAINDIR=%~dp1
SET CLEARCASE_FILE=%2
SET BRANCH_NAME=%3
SET SOURCE_DRIVE=T:
SET TARGET_TEMP_DIR=D:
SET DIFF_TARGET_FILE=D:\allPatch.diff
call set BASE_FILE=%%CLEARCASE_FILE:%BRANCH_NAME%=LATEST%%
call set TARGET_FILE=%%PLAINFILE:%SOURCE_DRIVE%=%TARGET_TEMP_DIR%%%
call set TARGET_DIR=%%PLAINDIR:%SOURCE_DRIVE%=%TARGET_TEMP_DIR%%%
echo Diffing file %PLAINFILE%
IF NOT EXIST %TARGET_DIR% mkdir %TARGET_DIR%
cleartool get -to %TARGET_FILE% %BASE_FILE%
diff -u %TARGET_FILE% %PLAINFILE% >> %DIFF_TARGET_FILE%
rem del /F/Q %TARGET_FILE%
```

And then I created a second bat file which simply takes the branch name as argument. In our case this directory contains multiple VOBs, so I iterate over them and do this per VOB.

```
@echo off
SET BRANCHNAME=%1
SET DIFF_TARGET_FILE=D:\allPatch.diff
SET SOURCE_DRIVE=T:
SET DIFF_TOOL=D:\Data\Scripts\diffClearCase.bat
IF EXIST %DIFF_TARGET_FILE% DEL /Q %DIFF_TARGET_FILE%
for /D %%V in ("%SOURCE_DRIVE%\*") DO (
    echo Checking VOB %%V
    cd %%V
    cleartool find %%V -type f -branch "brtype(%BRANCHNAME%)" -exec "%DIFF_TOOL% \"%%CLEARCASE_PN%%\" \"%%CLEARCASE_XPN%%\" %BRANCHNAME%"
)
```